How to determine which customer payment method to use with Stripe
My users will enter their payment method information when they sign up, and our system will charge them each month. (We are not using subscriptions because the amount will depend on usage.)
Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that Stripe has a concept of a default payment method. Since customers can have more than one payment method, how do I figure out which payment method to use?
I'm sure there's an API to query all the payment methods for a given customer, but what if there's more than one? How are people handling this?
UPDATE:
I tried the following to set the default payment method on the invoice.
InvoiceService invoiceService = new();
InvoiceCreateOptions invoiceCreateOptions = new()
{
    DefaultPaymentMethod = session.SetupIntent.PaymentMethodId,
    Customer = customer.Id,
};
Invoice invoice = await invoiceService.CreateAsync(invoiceCreateOptions);

CustomerGetOptions customerGetOptions = new()
{
    Expand = ["invoice_settings.default_payment_method"],
};
customer = await customerService.GetAsync(customer.Id, customerGetOptions);

However, the customer returned on the last line still has InvoiceSettings.DefaultPaymentMethod/InvoiceSettings.DefaultPaymentMethodId set to null.

Stripe uses the invoice_settings.default_payment_method property on a Customer to determine the default PaymentMethod to use for Subscriptions and Invoices. You don't use Subscriptions but can still use this property to keep track of a default payment method for a Customer for those one-off charges if a Customer has more than one PaymentMethod.
As an aside, if you did want to use Subscriptions, Stripe has a concept of usage-based billing where Customers can be charged at the end of a billing cycle/in arrears for usage they have accrued.

Thanks. I Added an invoice with the same customer and the payment method, but the invoice_settings.default_payment_method property on the customer still returns null. I added the code I'm using to the end of my question.

Ah, I think I see what's wrong. Your code is setting default_payment_method on the Invoice. That means that payment for that particular Invoice will be paid with the PaymentMethod you pass. Setting default_payment_method on the Invoice does not change/affect the invoice_settings.default_payment_method property on the Customer. Instead of setting a default PM on the Invoice, you should instead update the Customer's invoice_settings.default_payment_method.

Yes, I got that working. I thought the property was referencing an invoice. Thanks.
